# Creating/Generating Swagger UI from apiDefinition.swagger.json file/Creationg Swagger UI without using SwashBuckle

Tags: asp.net-web-api, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0, swashbuckle, swagger-codegen

I wanted to add swagger UI to one of our Asp.Net Web API projects. Tried installing SwashBuckle but it is not working because of some restrictions. So, checking for other ways. I have created apiDefinition.swagger.json file from postman collection. How can I create swagger UI from this? Also, please suggest other ways to create swagger UI.

what I have tried: Tried installing SwashBuckle but it is not creating swaggerconfig.cs file. When i checked the project dependencies, i saw that our controller is derived from a common controller that is in another project. This common controller is derived from ApiController. All the Controllers of the projects in the solution are derived from this common controller. So, we thought this approach might not work. So, checking for other ways. I could generate apiDefinition.swagger.json file using postman collection of our API's. Now, I want to know how I can use it for creating swagger UI.